# What is the fastest method to filter out duplicate CSS Rule using PHP?

Tags: php, css, string, preg-replace, string-matching

For example, I have the test.css with the following rule

```
.fs24 { font-size: 24px; }
.fc77777 { color: #777777; }
.fs24 { font-size: 20px; }
.fc77777 { color: #787878; }
```

What i want is, a php method to be able to take this input and output

```
.fs24 { font-size: 24px; }
.fc77777 { color: #777777; }
```

as you can see, I want to detect and filter out duplicate css rule by their **selector** . 3 premises must hold :

1. The filtered css rule can be 1 liner / multi line , all I care is as long as their **selector** have existed before, they must be filtered out!
2. There are many string manipulation technique for this, what I am trying to find out is the FASTEST possible method to do this, reason being the CSS I have in production should be quite big (we are trying to merge ALL CSS File into one and filtered out all duplicate rule out)
3. LIFO, Last In First Out, a.k.a the one that will NOT be filtered is the first CSS Rule, any other CSS Rule with duplicate **selector** will be removed entirely :|

Comment: 1. different selectors can point to the same element 2. have you tried anything or you just want us to do your work?

Comment: You are better off using an existing browser developer tool that has all this in place. Cascading in CSS is no small fry (that's why it's right in the name).

Comment: @Zerkms , What i am trying to achieve is to shrink 10 css files, into 1 css file, and i wishes to trim down the duplicate selector on server...

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to parse the input file(s) and build a dictionary of rules with the selectors as the dictionary keys.  For each rule, check if the selector is already in the dictionary.  If it is then discard the rule, otherwise add the new rule to the dictionary.

Once you've finished parsing the input, then create the new .css file from the contents of the dictionary.

You'd need to be careful with rules that have multiple selectors.  I'd probably create one dictionary entry for each selector, but without some additional processing you'll end up with duplication of code in your output file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input :) . One question arises, what is the fastest method to parse the input into a dictionary? Would you suggest any other method except using the Preg_match? (is there any other method that could do this except using the preg_match would be the better question?) :P

Comment: Using the Preg Match, I could use the following $pattern = '/(?P<selector>.*) {([^{}]*)}/';
 to output proper array preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches); that later can be used to create dictionary with ... However the main question remain clear, is this really the fastest method? I am really concern with this because the amount of CSS need to be parsed into single CSS file is tremendous in my Project, It my mission to find the most effective way (read : FASTEST) to handle this :) ... Please chip in any thing that you think could be potentially faster than what I have :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```css
.fs24 { font-size: 24px !important;}
.fc77777 { color: #777777 !important;}
```

Comment: No... It does not trim the css at all ... I want to make the css as small as possible, so eliminating the duplicates on server is important :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:
http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/?